# Machine Learning: How to learn MTG draft card game

Tags: machine-learning

I have become familiar with many various approaches to machine learning, but I am having trouble identifying which approach might be most appropriate for my given fun problem. (IE: is this a supervised learning problem and if so, what is my input x and output y?)

A magic the gathering draft consists of many actors sitting around a table holding a pack of 15 cards. the players pick a card and pass the remainder of the pack to the player next to them. They open a new pack and do this again for 3 total rounds (45 decisions). People end up with a deck which they use to compete.

I am having trouble understanding how to structure the data I have into trials which are needed for learning. I want a solution that 1) builds knowledge about which cards are picked relative to the previous cards that are picked 2) can then be used to make a decision about which card to pick from a given new pack.

I've got a dataset of human choices I'd like to learn from. It also includes info on cards they ended up picking but discarding ultimately. What might be an elegant way to structure this data for learning, aka, what are my features?

Comment: I think Machine Learning typically requires a 'fitness' to make a deterministic choice. In the case of cards being picked relative one another you'd need to give the cards some sort of scaling weight (like if you pick a blue card in some set it may have stronger complements within black or red, but not green or white). A total fitness would strengthen everything and could be found by actually playing out the selections and giving cohesion to the 45 cards (but then you have to consider the 40 card minimum deck and resource balance (lands)). Give cards individual weights too, Rarity/Power

Comment: It seems to me that a proper learning algorithm would be able to account for all of that. The only fitness (I think...) I need here is previous human choices, which are assumed to be fit.

Answer (score 2):

These kind of problems are usually tackled by **reinforcment learning**, **planning** and **markov decision processes**. Thus this is not oa typical scheme of supervised/unsupervised learning. This is rather about learning to play something - to interact with the environment (rules of the game, chances etc.). Take a look at methods like:

- Q-learning
- SARSA
- UCT

In particular, great book by Sutton and Barto "Reinforcement Learning: An Introduction" can be a good starting point.

Comment: i could see how reinforcement learning could be applied, but I was hoping for something more concrete and particular to my problem than 'read a book'. seems hyper elaborate. its not really interacting with an environment, i was hoping for a solution that just came up with fitness of future picks based on the previous choices.

Comment: The point is - there are no such answer for these kind of questions. This is about trial and error, there are dozens of approaches, hundreads of modifications and even more possibilities.

Comment: thanks for the reading suggestions. i narrowed my question a bit more.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can train a model do handle this -- eventually -- with either supervised or unsupervised learning.  The problem is the quantity of factors and local stable points.  Unfortunately, the input at this point is the state of the game: cards picked by all players (especially the current state of the AI's deck) and those available from the deck in hand.

Your output result should be, as you say, the card chosen ... out of those available.  I feel that you have a combinatorial explosion that will require either massive amounts of data, or simplification of the card features to allow the algorithm to extract a meaning deeper than "Choose card X out of this set of 8."

In practice, you may want the model to score the available choices, rather than simply picking a particular card.  Return rankings, or fitness metrics, or probabilities of picking each particular card.

You can supply some supervision in choice of input organization.  For instance, you can provide each card as a set of characteristics, rather than simply a card ID -- give the algorithm a chance to "understand" building a consistent deck type.

You might also wish to put in some work to abstract (i.e. simplify) the current game state, such as writing evaluation routines to summarize the other decks being built.  For instance, if there are 6 players in the group, and your RHO and his opposite are both building burn decks, you don't want to do the same -- RHO will take the best burn cards in 5 of 6 decks passed around, leaving you with 2nd (or 3rd) choice.

As for the algorithm ...
A neural network will explode with this many input variables.  You'll want something simpler that matches your input data.  If you go with abstracted properties, you might consider some decision-tree algorithm (Naive Bayes, Random Forest, etc.).  You might also go for a collaborative filtering model, given the similarities in situations.

I hope this helps launch you toward designing your features.  Do note that you're attacking a complex problem: one of the features that can make a game popular for humans is that it's *hard* to automate the decision-making.

Comment: do you think if the data were restructured into pairwise combinations of cards held vs card picked, that would simplify this any? i am not trying to involve any elaborate attribute schemes. it was my impression that if i had enough human pick data and it was properly processed the rest would take care of itself. i also don't see why you need an entire game state as opposed to just one seat.

Comment: Yes, those pairs would simplify the problem greatly, and would give you a decent starting model.  You'll still need a lot of human data.

Comment: As for needing the "game state", I'm assuming that the purpose of this model is to win the tournament among the players seated at the table.  To do this properly, you need to consider their picks as well, insofar as those affect the cards available when their decks reach you.

Comment: Consider the case where you're in seat 5 of 6, hoping to build a red/black deck.  Five rounds in, you see that the players in seats 1 and 4 are doing the same.  This means that for the remaining 40 picks you will get first choice of those cards only 1/6 of the time; player 4 will get first choice for decks starting from seats 2, 3, and4; player 1 will get first choice form decks starting from seats 6 and 1.  In short, *you will have only the third-best red/black deck at the table*.  You likely want to change your strategy to a style with less competition.

Answer (score 1):

1. Every single "pick" is a decision, with the input information as A:(what you already have), and B:(what the available choices are).
2. Thus, a machine that decides "whether you should pick this card", can be a simple binary classifier given the input of A+B+(the card in question).
3. For example, the pack 1 pick 2 of someone basically provides 1 "yes" (the card picked) and 13 "no" (the cards not picked), total 14 rows of training data.
4. We may want to weight these training data according to which pick it is. (When there are less cards left, the choice might be less important than when there are more choices.)
5. We may also want to weight these training data according to the rarity of cards.
6. Finally, the main challenge is that the input data (the features), A+B+card, is inappropriate unless we do a smart transformation. (Simply treating the card as a categorical variable and 1-hot coding them leads to something that is too big and very low information density. That will definitely fail.)
7. This challenge can be resolved by making it a 2-stage process. First we vectorize the cards, then build features based on the vectors.
   http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~mvolkovs/recsys2018_challenge.pdf